# Making a UILabel subview in UIScrollView to be firstResponder

Tags: uiscrollview, delegates, subview, tap, first-responder

I have added a label with some text and links to an ScrollView,
when you tap on those links (in the label), a delegate method will call, displays a popover  and show some related information.

but problem starts from here, I want when you tap on anywhere else except the links, the popover disappear.

if I add a  UITapGestureRecognizer to ScrollView, the delegate method for links won't call.

what should I do to label handles the tap on links, and ScrollView Handles the other taps?

I did like that:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void)tapped
{
    if ([self.storyText.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(attributedLabel:shouldFollowLink:)])

        [self.storyText.delegate performSelector:@selector(attributedLabel:shouldFollowLink:) withObject:self.storyText];
}
```

In tapped method Im checking if Im tapping on a link, the delegate should be called, but Delegate wont call.
Am I missing someThing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Solution:
first I create a custom class for my scrollView and subclassed that from UIScrollView.
Second I override

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in my custom ScrollView class. in this method I called a method to dismiss the popover.

but important part is that in viewWillAppear method of the class which popover will appear, I passed self to custom scrollView class. because if I didn't that, the method for dismissing popover won't work (it needs an object of this class).

```
[self.scrollView initWithStoryViewController:self];
```

[image]

this images show in which scenario I had this problem:

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom UIButtons instead of labels or you can place custom UIButtons with clear background color over the links and give actions to this buttons.

Comment: Im using OHAttributedLabel, so I can't use buttons.

Comment: What about placing custom UIButtons with clear background color over your labels and give the actions to the buttons?

Comment: I want to catch links on the UILabel, and those links are dynamically generated (number of them can be increased), so I can't add a button on those links.